# How can I recursively create class properties in Python?

Tags: python

Python supports creating properties "on the fly", like so.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

x = MyClass
x.new = 5
print(x.new)  # prints 5
```

But this is a tad ugly. I have to have some instruction within the class, either a function or a class property definition.

But the main hindrance is this...

```
x.first.second = 1  # this will raise
```

And it raises because first doesn't exist, obviously. I would have to do something like this instead.

```
x.first = MyClass()
x.first.second = 1
print(x.first.second)
```

I want to recursively create properties as they're needed. Is this possible?

Comment: See `__getattr__` and Friends: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/getattr.html , https://blog.rmotr.com/python-magic-methods-and-getattr-75cf896b3f88?gi=1d0896b83eb4 , https://medium.com/@satishgoda/python-attribute-access-using-getattr-and-getattribute-6401f7425ce6 - might be XY.

Comment: It doesn't just *support* it, it's the *primary* way to do it. That's all `__init__` does if you set the attributes there: `self.new = 5` is just adding the `new` attribute to the instance on the fly once `__init__` is invoked.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to do this, however. It plays havoc with the idea that a class is supposed to define how instances of the class behave, since the class now says nothing about what attributes an instance might have.

Comment: I'm using an api that returns many objects in a list, and I need to mock them out for testing. I only care about a subset of the properties of each object, but these properties are nested as in my example. It's 200% inconvenient to use argparser.Namespace or my class hack as in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `__getattr__` to create a new attribute namespace and return. `__eq__` is implemented. The behavior is similar to `types.SimpleNamespace`.

```
class Namespace:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        ret = Namespace()
        setattr(self, item, ret)
        return ret

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Namespace) and vars(self) == vars(other)


ns = Namespace()
ns.first.second = 1

print(ns.first.second)  # 1
```

However, this has side effect

```
print(ns.unknown)   # <__main__.Namespace object at 0x0000025FC1E5B400>
```

Comment: Please don't mess around with with `__dict__` directly. Just use `setattr(self, item, Namespace())`. You already know `item` doesn't name an existing attribute; `__getattr__` would not have been called if it did.

Comment: Hi, can you share some link for further reading or any insight about why should anyone avoid touching `__dict__` directly? @chepner

Comment: It's an implementation detail, and not even guaranteed to exist (see `__slots__`, for example).